# Meaning of f[u] in DFS algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I wonder what the $f[u]$ row means here, in this table that represents the DFS algorithm of the following graph.

I know $u$ is the order of visit of each node, $d[u]$ the cumulative time needed, and $\Pi[u]$ the father node, but I'm completely clueless about $f[u]$.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d[u]$ is the time in which $u$ was visited, and $f[u]$ is the time in which the algorithm was done with $u$ (i.e., finished visiting all vertices reachable from $u$)
Using the table you can see exactly how the algorithm went (and thus you know how to build the DFS tree/forest) : vertices 1,2,4,8 were visited (time 1-4) then got back from 8, then visited 12, then back from 12 etc.